# C++ удаление указателей в структуре

Tags: c++, delete

День добрый! Возможно ли при создании динамической структуры данных `struct* test=new struct`

записывать указатель на созданную структуру скажем в вектор `vector < struct > v` таким образом:

```
v.push_back(*test);
```

чтобы в определенный момент пробежаться по элементам вектора `v` и вызвать для них `delete`?

Если да, то как выглядит удаление указателей в векторе?(компилятор без 11+ стандарта)

Comment: нет, нельзя. У Вас в векторе не указатели, а значения.

Comment: @KoVadim а если vector < struct* > v ?

Comment: а так можно. ну кроме того, что никто не даст Вам назвать структуру именем struct

Comment: причем тут удаление указателей, к тому же и в структуре?

Comment: @Максим `for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) { delete v[i];} v.clear();`

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan интересно, можно ли завести структуру данных с указателями, чтобы ими можно было управлять через структуру данных

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, примерно так!

Comment: @Максим, почему нет? Можно конечно.

Comment: Можно ещё покороче: `for (auto* pElem : v) { delete pElem; } v.clear();`.  В основном на современных компиляторах range-based for несколько более оптимизирован, нежели цикл со счетчиком.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы написали, сработает, но с большим количеством оговорок.

Во-первых, при пуше в вектор собственных объектов (у вас это `*test`) вызывается конструктор копирования. Если в вашем объекте есть указатели, под которые динамически выделена память, то конструктор копирования по умолчанию просто присвоит новому экземпляру адрес, а не содержащиеся по нему данные. Поэтому, если память освободится в другом месте программы, то у объекта в векторе будет ссылка на очищенную память ==> возможна ошибка сегментации.

Таким образом, передавая в вектор `*test` вы создаёте новый экземпляр и старый экземпляр из вектора удалить не можете.

Во-вторых, можно удалить динамический объект по его адресу в принципе из любого места в программе. В вашем случае для этого достаточно сделать, как писали в комментариях:

```cpp
Object *obj = new Object;
vector<Object*> v;
v.push_back(obj);
...
...
...
for (vector<Object*>::iterator itr = v.begin(); itr != v.end(); ++itr) {
    delete *itr;     // разыменовывание итератора даёт указатель Object*
    *itr = nullptr;  // помогает избегать непредсказуемого поведения
}
v.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Для удаления динамического объекта я бы воспользовался более лаконичным циклом:

```cpp
Object *obj = new Object;
vector<Object*> v;
v.push_back(obj);

for (auto* elem : v) { 
    delete elem; 
} 
v.clear();
```

Comment: А я бы вообще не стал так делать, уж слишком много проблем.